# How to disable double tab to show available commands in Bash?

Tags: bash, key-binding

Is there a way to disable the double tab key behaviour (pressing tab twice shows available commands in Bash)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash uses readline for completion and key bindings.  You can set your own options in ~/.inputrc, and system wide options in /etc/inputrc.  If these do not exist, you can create them yourself.  These are read at shell login, so changes you make are not in effect until you create a new login shell.

If you want to disable completion entirely, you can use a typical GNU "yes to no":

```
set disable-completion on
```

If you want completion, but just not with tab, you can bind tab to insert itself:

```
TAB: self-insert
```

This will allow you to still use completion with ESC ESC, or you can bind completion to another key of your liking, e.g.  C-t:

```
TAB: self-insert
C-t: complete
```

There is a huge amount of customization you can do; I refer you to the [Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) and [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick and choose the key mappings you wish to disable without having to turn off autocomplete.

Example: To disable autocomplete for multiple Esc key presses add the following to your ~/.inputrc:

`"\e\e": ""`

Read the "Readline" section of the bash man page for detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable autocompletion completely. [Some information](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-can-i-disable-autocomplete-or-tab-complete-681839/):

> I depends on what exactly do you want
>   to do.
>
> If you just want to disable advanced
>   autocompletion you can either use
>   "complete -r" or remove
>   /etc/bash_completion*
>
> Reading the man page for "complete"
>   might help here. It's a shell thing,
>   it really doesn't have anything to do
>   with a particular distro or another.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility - disable bash (and friends) entirely! There are plenty of other shells to use on Linux.